# what is the opposite of "\n" in c++?

Tags: c, c++11, visual-c++

I want to know what is the opposite of getting a new line as in a command to go back to the previous line in output or to guide the pointer of the screen to the previous line.

Comment: You might find what you're looking for on [this page](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/escape).

Comment: The standard functionality provided by C++ is ignorant of such things as "previous lines". There are platform-specific functions you could call, or portable solutions like [ncurses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ncurses).